# How to get array key values from loop in Swift 3

Tags: ios, arrays, for-loop, swift3, swift2

I'm updating my code from Swift 2.3 to Swift 3, and I am facing these difficulties to get an array key value from a loop in Swift:

```
var countryarray = NSMutableArray()

self.GetCountriesResult = (responseJSON.objectForKey("GetCountriesResult") as? NSArray)!

for i in 0 ..< self.GetCountriesResult.count {
    self.countryarr = self.GetCountriesResult.objectAtIndex(i).objectForKey("countryname") as? String ?? ""
    self.countryarray.addObject(self.countryarr)
}
```

Comment: You are using Swift 3? Get rid of NSArray stuff (almost everything that starts with "NS") and use Swift type instead. What error did you get? My guess, Any doesn't have `objectForKey()` or something like that. It's a common issue. You need to tell the compiler that `self.GetCountriesResult.objectAtIndex(i)` is a `Dictionary` and that you can call `objectForKey` on it.

Comment: And error says?

Comment: If you can, provide a sample of your JSON response.

Answer (score 1):

`map` is better suited than `for-in` in this case:

```
guard let json = responseJSON["GetCountriesResult"] as? [String : AnyObject]
    else { return }

self.GetCountriesResult = json

let countryArray = self.GetCountriesResult.map {
    return $0["countryname"] as? String ?? ""
}

// OR

guard let json = responseJSON["GetCountriesResult"] as? [String : AnyObject]
    else { return }

let countries = json.map {
    return $0["countryname"] as? String ?? ""
}
```

Suggestion: Read the following Swift style guides:

- https://swift.org/documentation/api-design-guidelines/
- https://github.com/raywenderlich/swift-style-guide
- https://github.com/linkedin/swift-style-guide
- https://github.com/github/swift-style-guide